# How to change default permissions of root group on every newly created file?

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, root

I'm using CentOS. I have a user that is member of the root group.

All files created by a member of the root group have the following permissions: `rw-r--r--`
Is there a way to change this behaviour?

I want all files created by a root group member to have the permissions: `rw-rw-r--`

Comment: Look up `umask`, then, once you understand what it is and how to use it, set it to `002` for the user in question.